# wp_reset_postdata killing variable data

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created an archive page for a custom post type in Wordpress. I want to output data if certain fields match.

Within the first if statement, I want to check what product the user has signed up to (held within `$product` and match it against the current items custom field (held within `$title`).

All it's doing is seeing what the user signed up to then outputting the content (which is all the data below `<?php if($match == "yes"){ ?>`.

The problem I have is `wp_reset_postdata()` is killing the data held within `$match`. Is there a way around this? If I don't include the setting up of post data and don't include the reset then the rest of the page doesn't show the correct info.

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields relationship field (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/relationship/).

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
User signed up as: <?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$board = $current_user->work;
$product = $current_user->product;
echo $product; ?>
<br />

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php $products = get_field('product'); 
if( $products ):
    foreach( $products as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT)
        setup_postdata($post);          
        $title = $post->post_title;
        echo $title;
        if($product == $title) {
            $match = "yes";
        }
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly
endif; ?>   

<?php if($match == "yes"){ ?>
<div id="module-area" style="margin-top:0px!IMPORTANT;">
    <div id="modules-top"></div>
    <div id="modules-repeat" style="position:relative;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;width:625px!IMPORTANT;">
        <div class="topic">
            <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <p><?php the_field('description') ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="date">
            <p style="text-align:center!IMPORTANT;"><?php the_modified_time('d.m.y'); ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="action">
            <a class="train-button" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"></a>                      
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom:5px;" id="modules-bottom"></div>              
</div>  
<?php } ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Do you only want to show posts where $product == $title ? Or did you want it to show all unless $products is set?

Comment: @Damien Yes if $product == $title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User signed up as: <?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$board = $current_user->work;
$product = $current_user->product;
?>
<?php $products = get_field('product'); 
if( $products ):
    foreach( $products as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT)
        setup_postdata($post);          
        $title = $post->post_title;
        if($product == $title) { 
                       wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <div id="module-area" style="margin-top:0px!IMPORTANT;">
            <div id="modules-top"></div>
            <div id="modules-repeat" style="position:relative;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;width:625px!IMPORTANT;">
                <div class="topic">
                    <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    <p><?php the_field('description') ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="date">
                    <p style="text-align:center!IMPORTANT;"><?php the_modified_time('d.m.y'); ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="action">
                    <a class="train-button" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"></a>                      
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-bottom:5px;" id="modules-bottom"></div>              
        </div>  
<?php           
        }
    endforeach;
endif; ?>   
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave this a go earlier - the problem with it is that it's outputting the title (and other data) of the relationship field items rather than the actual custom post itself.

Comment: Updated answer.. Maybe try that? (sorry typo)

Comment: Hmm, the titles for each of the modules are different but the description, time and links are all for the first item in the list.

Comment: Interesting. Well I added back the wp_reset_postdata(); instruction. Does that help? Sorry - it's hard to work on this without actually seeing the deployment :)

Comment: That's better. Although the matching doesn't seem to be working - it's showing all the posts no matter if they match or not. Maybe I haven't done the matching part correctly???

Comment: I guess the part I am struggling with understanding here is the foreach loop - what are we trying to do there exactly?

Comment: Ok putting the html within the foreach loop shows the correct amount of posts but it doesn't show the right data. It's pulling in the title of the relationship field and not the title of the actual post itself.

Comment: Ok, think I have it working but not sure if this is good practice! As the html was showing the data of the relationship field, I put the reset underneath the line `if($product == $title) {`. It then works.

Comment: Ok. I was wondering if adding the_post() underneath would sort that out.. Good work anyway :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, your answers definitely helped!